# How can I add a comment list in my posts' index.html page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I add a comment list in my posts' index.html page?

It is my PostsController:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
end

# GET /posts/1
# GET /posts/1.json
def show
  @comments = @post.comments.all
  @comment = @post.comments.build
end
```

and its my posts show view:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <h3><%= @post.name %></h3>
</p>

<p>
  <%= (@post.descriptopm).html_safe %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post), :class => "btn btn-info btn-xs" %>
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path, :class => "btn btn-info btn-xs" %>

<h3>Comments</h3>
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <div>
    <strong><%= comment.user_name %></strong>
    <br />
    <p><%= (comment.body).html_safe %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= render 'comments/form' %>
```

and its my posts index view:

```
<h1>Listing posts</h1>
<%= link_to 'Create a New Post', new_post_path, :class => "btn btn-success btn-sm" %>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<div class="post thumbnail">
  <h3><%= post.name %></h3>
  <div><%= (post.descriptopm).html_safe %></div>

  <div class="bottom-bottoms">
    <%= link_to 'Display', post, :class => "btn btn-info btn-xs" %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post), :class => "btn btn-info btn-xs" %>
    <%= link_to 'Delete', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :class => "btn btn-info btn-xs" %>
  </div>

  <h3>Comments</h3>
  <% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <div>
      <strong><%= comment.user_name %></strong>
      <br />
      <p><%= (comment.body).html_safe %></p>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= render 'comments/form' %>

</div>
<% end %>
```

the post.rb :

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
end
```

the comment.rb :

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
end
```

the show page show the comments well but the index cannot...
it shows the error : undefined method `comments' for #
please help me >"<
I am a newly Ruby on Rails writer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Associations**

If you're using [ActiveRecord association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) to "link" your `Post` and `Comment` model, you'll be able to call `.comments` on each `post` you have in your index

Something to note (and this lies at the core of your error) is that you will have to call the `.comments` method on each `instance` of the `Post`. You're currently trying to call it on an `@instance variable` which doesn't exist:

```
#app/views/posts/index.html.erb
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
   <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
      <%= comment.body %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This, of course, is only possible by using the setup you have already (`has_many` / `belongs_to`):

```
#app/models/post.rb
Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :comments #-> post.comments
end

#app/models/comment.rb
Class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :post #-> comment.post
end
```

Comment: its seemed passed but showing Showing ....../app/views/comments/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
Extracted source (around line #1):
          
    `<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
       <% if @comment.errors.any? %>
         <div id="error_explanation">
           <h2><%= pluralize(@comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this comment from being saved:</h2>`

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/posts/index.html.erb

Comment: I set the @comment in my post controller and it works!!!
thanks a lot!
  `def index
     @posts = Post.all 
     @comment = Comment.new 
   end`

Comment: I have another problems here, Now it show the comment form correctly. But after I type some comment and confirm it, it does not show the comment I leaved. But when I leave a comment in the post page it works correctly. why?

its my new post controller here:

`def index` 
    `@posts = Post.all`
    `@comment = Comment.new`
  `end`

  `def show`
    `@comments = @post.comments.all`
    `@comment = @post.comments.build`
  `end`

Comment: Can you explain in more detail your new issue? It will likely be that your new comment is not being associated with a post, but I can't tell from what you've posted

Comment: Pech
I post it like an another question here
LINK : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276933/how-can-i-leave-a-comment-and-associate-with-the-post-in-post-index-page

thanks so much to save my quiestion :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of using @post in comment use post on index page. You have typo error.

```
<%= link_to 'Create a New Post', new_post_path, :class => "btn btn-success btn-sm" %>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<div class="post thumbnail">
  <h3><%= post.name %></h3>
  <div><%= (post.descriptopm).html_safe %></div>

  <div class="bottom-bottoms">
    <%= link_to 'Display', post, :class => "btn btn-info btn-xs" %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post), :class => "btn btn-info btn-xs" %>
    <%= link_to 'Delete', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :class => "btn btn-info btn-xs" %>
  </div>

  <h3>Comments</h3>
  <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <div>
      <strong><%= comment.user_name %></strong>
      <br />
      <p><%= (comment.body).html_safe %></p>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= render 'comments/form' %>

</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: its seemed passed but showing Showing ....../app/views/comments/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
Extracted source (around line #1):
          
    `<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
       <% if @comment.errors.any? %>
         <div id="error_explanation">
           <h2><%= pluralize(@comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this comment from being saved:</h2>`

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/posts/index.html.erb

Comment: I set the @comment in my post controller and it works!!!
thanks a lot!
  `def index
     @posts = Post.all 
     @comment = Comment.new 
   end`