# How can I leave a comment and associate with the post in post' index page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I leave a comment and associate with the post in post' index page?

It is my PostsController:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
  "what should I add here?"
end

# GET /posts/1
# GET /posts/1.json
def show
  @comments = @post.comments.all
  @comment = @post.comments.build
end
```

and its my posts show view:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <h3><%= @post.name %></h3>
</p>

<p>
  <%= (@post.descriptopm).html_safe %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post), :class => "btn btn-info btn-xs" %>
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path, :class => "btn btn-info btn-xs" %>

<h3>Comments</h3>
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <div>
    <strong><%= comment.user_name %></strong>
    <br />
    <p><%= (comment.body).html_safe %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= render 'comments/form' %>
```

and its my posts index view:

```
<h1>Listing posts</h1>
<%= link_to 'Create a New Post', new_post_path, :class => "btn btn-success btn-sm" %>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<div class="post thumbnail">
  <h3><%= post.name %></h3>
  <div><%= (post.descriptopm).html_safe %></div>

  <div class="bottom-bottoms">
    <%= link_to 'Display', post, :class => "btn btn-info btn-xs" %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post), :class => "btn btn-info btn-xs" %>
    <%= link_to 'Delete', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :class => "btn btn-info btn-xs" %>
  </div>

  <h3>Comments</h3>
  <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <div>
      <strong><%= comment.user_name %></strong>
      <br />
      <p><%= (comment.body).html_safe %></p>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= render 'comments/form' %>

</div>
<% end %>
```

the post.rb :

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
end
```

the comment.rb :

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
end
```

the show page's comment function looks right
but when I leave a comment in my post's index page
It might not save the comment with the right post's id
how do I fix it?

and onother one:
how can I redirect the page to the index page after I save the comment not to comment's index page?

Comment: Just a note: you probably don't want to use `html_safe` on `comment.body` since I'm assuming it's entered by a user... and could be unsafe!

Comment: but I use ckeditor on it. I use `html_safe` for turning html code to page....

Comment: It's not a problem running locally, but once you put it on the internet you're gonna get comments with spam links and potentially other bad things.  I would check out [Rails' Sanitize Helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html) to whitelist allowed tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I leave a comment and associate with the post in post' index
>   page?

There are several things to consider:

---

**Comment Objects**

Firstly, you need to appreciate that since Rails is an *object orientated* framework (by virtue of being built on Ruby), you will need to ensure your new comment corresponds with the relevant `Post` object

I think this the core of what you're getting confused about:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
  # Here needs to go your "comment" build methodology. Except, it only works *per* post ;)
end
```

The trouble you have is that you can't "build" a comment for `Posts` - you have to build them *per* post, like this:

```
@post = Post.find 2
@post.comments.new #-> allows you to create a new comment for that particular post
```

--

**Implementation**

The best solution I can give you will be somewhat constricted, but will serve your purposes correctly. Here it is:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
Class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @posts = Post.all
      @comment = Comment.new
   end
end

#app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
Class CommentsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
      @comment.save
   end

   private

   def comment_params
       params.require(:comment).permit(:comment, :params, :post_id)
   end
end
```

This will take into consideration that for each comment on your `index`, you'll have a form with the `post_id` attached; *and* will be a "linear" flow (IE you can only post a single comment at a time):

```
#app/views/posts/index.html.erb
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
   <%= post.title %>
   <%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :post_id, value: post.id %>
      <%= f.text_field :title %>
      <%= f.submit %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Yes, this *will* give each `Post` a "new comment" form on your index page (hence my denoting its constriction). However, what it will do is give you the ability to add a comment for any of the posts on the page, handling them with the `CommentsController`

Comment: I think I just missing the `value: post.id`

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second second question, you can use

```
redirect_to post_index_path
```

As for the first question, you can set the post id of the post by using:

```
@post.comments.new
```

Instead of just Comment.new, which won't set the ID of the post.

Comment: 1. where should I add this code?
2. I use `@comment = @post.comments.new` in my index, but it shows the error: undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass

Comment: It seems I misread, your question, but I'm confused about what you're trying to accomplish by showing a __new__ comment on your posts index page. It seems that you have it setup so that comments belong to a certain post, and not the entire index. So why would you be creating a new comment on the index page?

Comment: Took a look at your edit, and I'm not sure what else you want to display on the index page? Just having the @posts will allow you to display all of your posts. Did you want something else..?

Comment: I can create comment in a post's show page associated with the post.
But in my index page. it can show the comment I created at post's show view but when I create a new one in posts' index page, the comment does not associate with the post why?

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario...this is the best example that you can get help

- [Railscasts show post with comments using polymorphism](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association)